# How to change the method of chained calls at runtime?

Tags: typescript

[LiveDemo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Chain%3CT%20%3D%20number%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20Omit%3Cthis%2C%20'fun1'%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun2(arg%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20Omit%3Cthis%2C%20'fun2'%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun3()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20unknown%20as%20Chain%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20case1%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%20%2F%2F%20it's%20ok%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20case2%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun3()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun2('')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun2(1)%20%2F%2F%20it'ok%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20case3%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun2(1)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%20%2F%2F%20expect%20a%20compiler%20error)

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

class Chain<T = number> {
    fun1() {
      return this as Omit<this, 'fun1'>
    }

    fun2(arg: T) {
      return this as Omit<this, 'fun2'>
    }

    fun3() { 
      return this as unknown as Chain<string>
    }
}

// case1
new Chain()
    .fun1()
    .fun1() // it's ok

// case2
new Chain()
    .fun3()
    .fun2('')
    .fun1()
    .fun2(1) // it'ok

// case3
new Chain()
    .fun1()
    .fun2(1)
    .fun1() // expect a compiler error
```

As can be seen from the above code, typescript can "remember" a change in generics for a chain call, but "can't remember" the changes to the method.

So, how to make case3 also ok?

Comment: This isn't exactly correct. The problem is you are omitting from `this` and not the type the call was made from. I don't think is this possible, it would require referring to the inferred type in code.

Comment: @AvinKavish `this` is a runtime type.

Comment: There are no runtime types in typescript because it gets compiled to javascript before running

Comment: @AvinKavish So, why case2 is ok? `fun3` changed the arg type of `fun2`

Comment: It's not okay, you are calling `fun2` twice

Comment: And I think, even if the runtime type is not supported, these cases should be able to get the results I want during the compilation phase.

Comment: Yes, just because I called twice, I think the parameter type of `fun2` has been changed dynamically and permanently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195013/discussion-between-aweiu-and-avin-kavish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aweiu Lots of things become possible if you accept how hideous they look :D
I've used [explicit this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions) parameter, made it generic and constrained to `Partial<Chain<T>>`.

Here's [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Chain%3CT%20%3D%20number%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun1%3CT1%20extends%20Partial%3CChain%3CT%3E%3E%3E(this%3A%20T1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20Omit%3CT1%2C%20'fun1'%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun2%3CT1%20extends%20Partial%3CChain%3CT%3E%3E%3E(this%3A%20T1%2C%20arg%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20Omit%3CT1%2C%20'fun2'%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fun3%3CT1%20extends%20Partial%3CChain%3CT%3E%3E%3E(this%3A%20T1)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20unknown%20as%20Omit%3CPick%3CChain%3Cstring%3E%2C%20Extract%3Ckeyof%20T1%2C%20keyof%20Chain%3Cstring%3E%3E%3E%2C%20'fun3'%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%20%2F%2F%20errors%20as%20expected%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun2(1)%20%2F%2F%20only%20fun3%20left%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Chain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun1()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.fun3()%20%2F%2F%20only%20fun2%20left%20and%20it%20takes%20a%20string)